# IIS's website and RDP listening on the same port with two NIC configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, remote-server, remote-desktop

I am working on a project that would allow customer to connect to an instance on port 443 and browse and use RemoteApps (site) hosted on the same server also on port 443 in a workgroup environment. Domain is not an option. The goal is to have only port 80 and 443 open on the same machine and have two services sharing the same port.

This is what I did so far:

1.Configured all the necessary components for RemoteApps 
2.Attached two network interfaces to the same instance. The idea behind it that the RemoteApp website will listen on one of interfaces (for example, eth0) port 443 and RDP connection will listen on the other interface (eth1) port 443.
3.In registry, I configured RDP to listen on port 443 instead of 3389 (Listen on both interfaces for now). I was able to connect to the machine using port 443. 
4. When I tried to set up RemoteApp website to listen on IP address of the other  interface, I get an error that other application is using the service.
5. Next I configured RDP registry to listen to only eth1 interface, rebooted the server and can't log in anymore.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Besides, the setup up is on Server 2008 R2

Comment: If the two NICs are configure with unique IP addresses this should be possible. You'll need to unbind IIS from using all IPs and only have it listen on IP1:443. That will allow RDP to bind to IP2:443.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it again just to see if it works. I actually made it work with a different set up.